# Print output of two commands in one line

Tags: bash, shell

I'm got this working:

```
while sleep 5s
 do
  lscpu | grep 'CPU MHz:' | cut -d ':' -f 2 | awk '{$1=$1};1' && grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat | awk '{usage=($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)} END {print usage "%"}'
done
```

And it gives me the following output:

```
1601.058
3.4811%
1452.514
3.48059%
1993.800
3.48006%
2085.585
3.47955%
2757.776
3.47902%
1370.237
3.47851%
1497.903
3.47798%
```

But I'd really like to get the two values onto a single line. Every time I try to do this I run into a double / single quote variable issue. Granted I pulled some of this awk stuff from online so I'm not really up to speed on that. I just want to print per line, CPU clock and load ever 5 seconds.

Can you help me find a better way to do that?

Comment: Consider [edit]ing to show something you're trying that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing this for readability rather than efficiency, you might consider something like:

```
while sleep 5; do
  cpu_pct=$(lscpu | awk -F': +' '/CPU MHz:/ { print $2 }')
  usage=$(awk '/cpu / {usage=($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)} END {print usage "%"}' /proc/stat)
  printf '%s\n' "$cpu_pct $usage"
done
```

Command substitutions implicitly trim trailing newlines, so if `lscpu | awk` has output that ends in a newline, `var=$(lscpu | awk)` removes it; thereafter, you can use `"$var"` without that newline showing up.

Comment: Thanks for the super fast reply, and also the suggestion of posting my failure.

Answer (score 3):

You may use process substitution to run `lscpu` and `cat /proc/stat` and feed to single command. No need to use pipes.

```
while sleep 5; do
    awk '/CPU MHz:/{printf "%s ", $NF} /cpu /{print ($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)"%"}' <(lscpu) /proc/stat
 done
```

If there is only one input command:

```
date| awk '{print $1}'
Wed
```

OR

```
awk '{print $NF}' <(date)
2019
```

If more then one command: Example , get the year of of the two date command in same line. (not very useful example, only for sake of demo)

```
awk '{printf "%s ", $1=NF}END{print ""}' <(date) <(date)
2019 2019
```

Comment: Good answer. One quibble: `<(cat /proc/stat)` could just be `/proc/stat`; no reason for a separate process and a FIFO to connect it.

Answer (score 1):

pipe the output of the 2 commands into `paste`

```
while sleep 5; do
    lscpu | awk -F':[[:blank:]]+' '$1 == "CPU MHz" {print $2}'
    awk '$1 == "cpu" {printf "%.4f%%\n", ($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)}' /proc/stat
done | paste - -
```

The 2 columns will be separated by a tab.

Comment: You could just have one `paste` reused rather than restarting a new one per loop iteration, no? That is: `while sleep 5; do ...; done | paste - -`

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change the newline on the first line to a different separator.  Something like:

```
lscpu | ... | tr \\n : && grep ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `echo -n $(command_with_stdout)`. The `-n` switch specifies that the new line (`\n`) will be omitted.

```
while sleep 5s; do
  echo -n $( lscpu | grep 'CPU MHz:' | cut -d ':' -f 2 | awk '{$1=$1};1' )
  echo -n ' **** '
  echo $( grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat | awk '{usage=($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)} END {print usage "%"}' )
done
```

Or the same representation in one line:

```
while sleep 5s; do echo -n $( lscpu | grep 'CPU MHz:' | cut -d ':' -f 2 | awk '{$1=$1};1' ); echo -n ' **** '; echo $( grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat | awk '{usage=($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)} END {print usage "%"}' ); done
```

EDIT: (remove `-n` switch from `echo` according to Charles Duffy's comment)

```
while sleep 5s; do echo "$( lscpu | grep 'CPU MHz:' | cut -d ':' -f 2 | awk '{$1=$1};1' ) **** $( grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat | awk '{usage=($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)} END {print usage "%"}' )"; done
```

Comment: `echo -n` is not reliable -- [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) lets it do *literally anything* when given that argument, including printing `-n` on output; and some runtime configurations of bash do exactly that. Much safer to use `printf '%s' "..."` instead of `echo -n "..."`.

Comment: (If reviewing the above link, be sure to hit both the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections)

Comment: ...also, it needs to be `echo -n "$(command_with_stdout)"` *with the quotes* if you don't want a `*` to be replaced with filenames, a tab to be replaced with a space, etc; relevant discussion in [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: (With respect to the "some runtime configurations" assertion, try running `set -o posix; shopt -s xpg_echo; echo -n foo` -- keep in mind that those flags can also be set through environment variables or at compile-time for the shell itself, so the above code isn't the only way to get into that state; and some other shells behave that way out-of-the-box).

Comment: Quotations are a bit more complicated and not clear. There are many "Shells" in different Linux systems. If I use quotation marks, then I can not use other features or I have to use them other than I'm accustomed to. The same applies to brackets. POSIX is also very ridiculous. Most shell creators ignoring the POSIX. Even between the two popular "Sh" and "Bash" are great differences. Due to differences "Sh" vs. "Bash" has stopped working one of the projects in the company for the whole week :-). Some ignorant brought into our system the Sh script, not the Bash script used in our company.

Comment: If your code only "works" without quotes, that code has serious bugs (some discussed in the BashPitfalls link above, others discussed in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)). bash is a POSIX-family shell; unlike zsh, it follows POSIX rules, and POSIX quoting guidelines *do* apply in their entirety when writing code for bash.

Comment: POSIX is really funny. I've been sitting behind the Linux system 20 years ago. Shell presented something different than today :). Today POSIX is just a big mess. Everyone develops their own Shell in which nothing works under POSIX. If the script works well on a particular system, on a particular kernel, in a particular Shell, there is no reason to worry about it. It's just a script and not an app. Shell scripting is just my little hobby :). Please do not ask for standards and normalization. It's tiresome. Anyway, thank you for your direction and your warning. I appreciate it.